# Avoiding if/else statements in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

AFAIK I should avoid if/else statements as much as I can.

I've chosen this approach and I'm looking to see if it is valid.

```java
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloController.class.getResource("UserPanel.fxml"));
if(receivedJSON.get("isAdmin").toString().equals("1")) {
    fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloController.class.getResource("AdminPanel.fxml"));
}

//....
//....
//code that needs to be run so I can't return in the if statement
//....
```

I don't really like it because if the `isAdmin` attribute is 1, I have to do two assignments.

What would be the best and professional way to avoid an if/else in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: and ... why should you avoid if-else statements?

Comment: @Stultuske good practice, as far as I know

Comment: OK.. allow me to rephrase. What makes you think that this is good practice?

Comment: @Stultuske from a teacher who's very good in C++ (and I suppose it works the same in the other programming languages) I had understood that each if/else/else if creates another branch when the program is compiled.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu 1) your teacher being good with C++ doesn't mean that knowledge translates well to Java; 2) I don't think that's true even in C++. Either he explained badly or you understood something else. Branching is fundamental in any programming language.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu now that I think about it, your teacher was probably thinking about [branch *prediction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor), which can cause performance penalty when the prediction is wrong, but that doesn't mean `if`s are bad.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that was the reason, as I recall. I might be wrong though - one thing that I'm sure about is that she recommended me to avoid if/else as much as I can. So - should I avoid if/else statements, or not? :)

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu No, you shouldn't :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I will look into that link. Thanks!

Comment: this looks like plain java, where do you see the relation to javafx?

Comment: the _professional way_ would be to avoid premature micro-optimizations :) Your snippet looks like suboptimal logic/class structure (f.i. instantiating a loader for a user if you replace it with the loader for the admin based on a condition that you seem to know before creating any).

Comment: Alternatively, consider using the [_strategy pattern_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to load the correct view.

Comment: Read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084

Comment: Please review [Clarification of "avoid if-else" advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/206867) on software engineering StackExchange.  Apply what you learned to the code in your question. Then, if you can, contact the C++ instructor and discuss what you learned with them, that way I think you will better understand the true intent of their instruction.

Comment: It is closed, so I can't answer, but, I'd write it this way: create a method `boolean isAdmin(JsonObject json) { return json.get("isAdmin").toString().equals("1"); }` create a method `Parent loadView(String viewName) { \* create a loader, load the viewName fxml and return the parent *\ }`, then I'd write `Parent view = isAdmin(receivedJSON) ? loadView("AdminPanel") : loadView("UserPanel"`);` then proceed with your "code that needs to be run".

Comment: I try to divide code (especially expressions) into small testable functions. Any piece of code is easy to read and understand within a couple of seconds, the code is self-documenting.  The code can be refactored, assigning small methods to appropriate objects and object patterns.  I try to make stuff immutable and functional rather than procedural, reducing complexity.  Sometimes you have a long procedure or algorithm where it is best not to do this, so don't apply it always, but apply it far more often than you might think you should and you usually end up with better code IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guidance to not use `if` if possible only applies if you optimize code that you execute millions of times per second. You probably only create a very small amount of FXMLLoaders each time you run the program.
Even if you estimate a high amount of 40 CPU cycles lost, at 4 Ghz that is still only 10 nanoseconds on a failed branch, so nothing you should worry about.

In fact, even if you only take 1 minute to write this post, and you create 100 FXMLLoaders (1 microsecond in total), and the branch predictor fails 100 times in a row (will not happen), it still took 60 million times longer to write the post than the time you could theoretically save.

Or if you create a server program and you only need 1 minute to optimize it and it creates one FXMLLoader in an if statement per second and the branch prediction fails every time, then that server needs to run for 190 years continuously for it to be worth it even if you value server single core CPU time the same way as developer time.

Comment: Moreover, you're presumably going to use each `FXMLLoader` to parse an FXML file and create a bunch of UI objects from it. That's an expensive process, and it's simply not viable to perform that enough times to make any savings (if indeed there are any) from "avoiding `if`" measurable.